# High Sierra and Bootcamp with Windows 10 not working

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, high-sierra

I'm having an issue getting my MBP High Sierra 10.13.2 (17C88) to function with Windows 10 on Bootcamp. I've used the bootcamp assistant to successfully partition out 85GB of space from 250GB APFS mac partition and download the windows support software - but then after restart nothing happens. There is a black screen with a delay (where otherwise Windows should load) and then it goes back to loading OSX.

I've been really struggling with getting this working on my mac, before updates to Windows 10 or to OSX, I had a fully functioning system, but then issues on the bootcamp partition (blue screens, driver errors) forced me to wipe the bootcamp partition. After wiping I tried reinstalling Windows but nothing worked. Then I wiped my whole OSX through recovery and restarted the process, and now I am stuck here. So I am installing bootcamp on an untouched, new OSX system.

Output from diskutil list:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         165.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                85.8 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +165.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            156.3 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.4 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.0 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +49.3 MB    disk4
   1:                  Apple_HFS Keka                    49.2 MB    disk4s1
```

Comment: When was your MBP made? Do you know early, mid, late year?

Comment: It was made in Early 2015

Comment: Post the output from the command `diskutil list`. Most likely, you did something wrong. Although, the problem may be with APFS. I know Windows users have complained they can not boot back to macOS directly from Windows when APFS is used. So is your question: how to install Windows 10 without using the Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: I've added the output to the post edit. I'm fine with using any method - my goal is just to get Windows 10 running on my Mac, with or without Bootcamp assistant.

Answer (score 3):

These are the basic steps needed to install Windows 10 for an EFI boot.

The Windows specifications are given below.

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 1709
- OS Build: 16299.15

> Note: To get a better view of the images shown below, either click on an image or open an image in a new window.

1. Use the Boot Camp Assistant to download the Window Support Software. Look for the "Action" pulldown on the Boot Camp Assistant menu bar. On my Mac, these files were downloaded to the `~/WindowsSupport` directory.
2. Remove all external drives and restart the Mac. The output you posted from `diskutil list` shows a `disk4`. You should confirm this disk image has been removed.
3. Insert a 16 GB or larger USB flash drive. Use the Disk Utility application to erase this drive, as shown below.

   [image: d0]
4. Your internal disk already has a 85.8 GB "BOOTCAMP" partition. The space occupied by this partition will be used for installing Windows.
5. Mount the Windows iso file and copy the contents to the "WINSTALL" volume. In my case, the label "ESD-ISO" was used to identify the Windows iso. To perform the copy operation, you will need the enter the `cp` command from a Terminal application window. Below is the exact command I usually used. If necessary, make the appropriate modifications.

   ```
   cp  -Rv  /volumes/ESD-ISO/  /volumes/WINSTALL
   ```

   > Note: This command will take a while to complete. Be patient!
6. Copy the Windows Support Software to the "WINSTALL" volume. Below is the exact command I usually use. If necessary, make the appropriate modifications.

   ```
   cp  -Rv  ~/WindowsSupport/  /volumes/WINSTALL
   ```
7. Use the command shown below to rename the `AutoUnattend.xml` file.

   ```
   mv  /volumes/WINSTALL/AutoUnattend.xml  /volumes/WINSTALL/NoAutoUnattend.xml
   ```
8. Next, you need to boot from the volume where the Windows installation files reside. Hold down the option key immediately after restarting on your Mac. Release the option when the Startup Manager window appears. Select the icon labeled "EFI boot". Next, select the arrow below the "EFI boot" label.
9. Open a Windows Command Prompt window, by following the procedure outlined in this step. Below is an image of what is initially displayed by the Windows 10 installer. Select "Next".

   [image: z1]

   In the image shown below, select "Repair your computer".

   [image: z2]

   In the image shown below, select "Troubleshoot".

   [image: z3]

   In the image shown below, select "Command Prompt".

   [image: z4]

   The result should be the image shown below.

   [image: z6]
10. Use the command `diskpart` to finish partitioning `disk0`. The commands you need to enter are given below.

    > Note: Sometimes it can take a while for the `diskpart` command to produce the first prompt. Be patient.

    ```
    diskpart
    list  volume
    ```

    From the output of the command `list volume`, determine the number for the volume with the label "BOOTCAMP". In this example, I will assume the number is `0`. Your number could be different. The next command selects this partition.

    ```
    select  volume  0
    ```

    The next commands effect the "BOOTCAMP" volume. The format is changed to NTFS. Next, the size is shrunk by 600 MB.

    ```
    format  fs=ntfs  label=BOOTCAMP  quick
    shrink  desired=600
    ```

    Create a Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) partition. The next commands create and initialize an empty 600 MB WinRE.

    ```
    create  partition  primary
    set  id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
    gpt  attributes=0x8000000000000001
    format  fs=ntfs  label="Recovery"  quick
    ```

    The next command lists the current volumes. Take note of the drive letter (Ltr) for the volume with label "WINSTALL". In this example, I will assume the letter is `D`. Your letter could be different.

    ```
    list  volume
    ```

    The command below quits the command `diskpart`.

    ```
    exit
    ```
11. Enter the command below to start the Windows installation. If the drive letter, for the "WINSTALL" volume, is not `D`, then make the appropriate substitute when entering the command below.

    ```
    setup  /unattend:D:\NoAutoUnattend.xml
    ```
12. When the window shown below appears, select the "BOOTCAMP" partition, then click on the "Next" button.

    [image: d1]
13. Continue with the installation of Windows 10. If the computer boots back to macOS, goto System Preferences and select Windows as your startup disk. Restart the computer to continue initializing Windows 10.
14. When finished, the Windows Support Software installer should automatically launch. If this does **not** occur, use the Windows File Explorer to open the Windows Support Software application named "Setup". This application can be found in the "BootCamp" folder on the "WINSTALL" drive. After the installer application completes, allow the computer to restart.

If asked, I can clarify any of the above steps.

Comment: The above routine did not work for me. It did not recognize the usb drive at boot time as boot drive.

Comment: @Elik: Not all Mac models can boot Windows 10 from a USB port. What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of Windows 10 and macOS are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to get this done, but I read that because Apple FIle system is not supported by boot camp yet, it is not possible. Does your method work with APFS? I've only one drive of 250G and i wanna duall boot for like 150 and 100 gb

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, Disconnect every single drive besides the one you are installing windows on, restart holding option, boot from CD/DVD and install windows, after you are done reconnect the drives