# Difficulties Reinstalling Windows on bootcamp with APFS

Tags: bootcamp, windows, apfs

I installed bootcamp a few years ago and now Windows is pretty hosed so I want to do a fresh install.  Apple says to delete the bootcamp partition in bootcamp assistant (BCA), and then redo it.

issue is that the SSD got converted to APFS, so when I go into BCA, it immediately says: "The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition. The startup disk must be formatted as a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by boot camp assistant for Installing Windows"

I read elsewhere to delete the bootcamp partition with APFS, can either use disk utility or terminal commands.  But if I do that, I suspect I will get same message in BCA and won't be able to create a new partition.

So what is best way to just nuke the bootcamp partition and re-install windows 10 Oct 2018 version?

MacBook Pro 2016, 10.13.6.  output from diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         798.7 GB   disk0s2
3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                200.8 GB   disk0s3
4:           Windows Recovery                         924.8 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +798.7 GB   disk1
                              Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            749.9 GB   disk1s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 19.0 MB    disk1s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                515.0 MB   disk1s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

thanks

Comment: Start up updating you question with the output from `diskutil list`. Also add the model/year of your Mac, the current version of macOS installed and the version of Windows you wish to install. If you are installing Windows 10, the add the release if known. For example the last two releases were  April 2018 (1803) and  October 2018 (1809).

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with this info:
[High Sierra and Bootcamp with Windows 10 not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313007/high-sierra-and-bootcamp-with-windows-10-not-working)

also this was helpful:

https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/